# Missing data imputation in univariate meta analysis with binary data using WinBUGS

Tags: binary-data, meta-analysis, bugs

I want to impute missing data in univariate meta-analysis. My outcome (no. fractures) is a binary variable. Below is the `WinBUGS` code I have tried. The code is compiled and I got an output. My question is, why there are no meaningful values in this output, i.e. why most of them are zeros?

```
model{
for(i in 1:11)
{

rt[i]~dbin(pt[i],nt[i])
rc[k]~dbin(pc[i],nc[i])
phi[i]<-logit(pc[i])

logit(pt[i])<-phi[i]+theta[i]

theta[i]~dnorm(mu,t)

pc[i]~dunif(0,1)


}
mu~dunif(-4,4)
tau.sqrd~dunif(0,3)
t<-1/tau.sqrd

OR<-exp(mu)

}
list(rt=c(17,175,9,2,14,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),rc=c(107,181,20,6,35,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),nt=c(1372,627,66,23,91,30,17,161,167,33,126), nc=c(1381,635,66,24,99,33,19,164,167,30,129))
```

This is the output I have got

```
node     mean    sd     MC error    2.5%    median  97.5%   start   sample
    OR  0.3913  0.239   0.00314   0.1184    0.3414  0.9814  3000    7001
rc[6]   16.39   9.802   0.1048    0.0       16.0    33.0    3000    7001
rc[7]   9.508   5.724   0.07085   0.0        9.0    19.0    3000    7001
rc[8]   82.06   47.69   0.5446    4.0       82.0    160.0   3000    7001
rc[9]   83.56   48.85   0.6197    4.0       83.0    164.0   3000    7001
rc[10]  15.06   8.998   0.08587   0.0       15.0    30.0    3000    7001
rc[11]  64.14   37.57   0.4124    2.0       64.0    126.0   3000    7001
rt[6]   10.24   9.191   0.1113    0.0        7.0    29.0    3000    7001
rt[7]   5.853   5.349   0.06115   0.0        4.0    17.0    3000    7001
rt[8]   55.35   48.6    0.5245    0.0       41.0    156.0   3000    7001
rt[9]   58.0    51.05   0.6429    0.0       42.0    162.0   3000    7001
rt[10]  11.52   10.22   0.1186    0.0        8.0    32.0    3000    7001
rt[11]  43.7    38.54   0.4732    0.0       32.0    123.0   3000    7001
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, there are no meaningful values in this output.(most of them are zeros)

The fact that your 2.5% quantiles are mostly zeros, that is not meaningless information, and it might indicate that your data contains a lot of zeros.

This makes me think of a [zero-inflated model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model) or discrete data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.                                                                                                                               when  I removed missing data (NA) and compiled this code again, I got the same value for the OR. I think there is some problem with the missing data imputation procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll refer to the zero-inflated model which you mentioned here. when I removed missing data (NA) and compiled this code again, I got the same value for the OR. I think there is some problem with the missing data imputation procedure.

Comment: @MAttanayaka possibly I do not understand your problem. Could you explain why you believe that the values are not meaningful.

Comment: Actually, I want to impute missing data. When I remove all the missing data and compiled code with only completed data, then I got the result of OR=0.39. When I impute missing data, then I got again the same result for the OR. That's why I believe that some problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The model will not impute the missing observations. Studies with double-zeros (or no events) do not contribute to the analysis. Still, you can see the posterior (predicted)  number of successes per group for each study with missing counts. The median/mean counts are shrunken toward the summary mean.

Comment: Thank You for your comments.                                                                                             
There are no zero events in my data set. Can you give me more explanation about the other option you have mentioned here?

Comment: Studies both double zeros or both NR in the events cells do not contribute to the analysis.

Comment: I got it. I am not clear about the option which you have suggested based on the posterior. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Based on what you described, you are not imputing counts, and you are just seeing the posterior distribution of counts - given the evidence available in the meta-analysis. If you have more specific questions, we can help more.